# Why while i want to open a second window on my Qt app, my header file does not recognize the second window?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qmainwindow, qdialog

i'm stuck with this for 2 days..

My code was building without any problems but since i made some changes that are not related with this (i think) it's not building anymore.

So i want to open a new window from a button clicked on a first window to open a second one and close the first one. I did as I saw in different tutorials.
But the fact is that my firstWindow header doesn't recognize my secondWindow type and my error is :

```
C:\Users\johns\Documents\ESI\2Bac\2020-2021\dev4\pokerCafards\pokerCafards\guiApp\firstwindow.h:45: error: 'gameWindow' does not name a type; did you mean 'QMainWindow'?
In file included from gamewindow.h:6,
                 from gamewindow.cpp:1:
firstwindow.h:45:5: error: 'gameWindow' does not name a type; did you mean 'QMainWindow'?
     gameWindow* gameWind;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     QMainWindow
```

As gameWindow is my secondWindow.

Here are my differents codes :

firstwindow.h

```
#ifndef FIRSTWINDOW_H
#define FIRSTWINDOW_H

#include "gamewindow.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "player.h"

namespace Ui {
class firstWindow;
}


class firstWindow : public QMainWindow
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit firstWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~firstWindow();

    std::vector<metier::Player> getPlayers();

    std::string getLineEditNameText();

    std::string getLineEditAgeText();

    void setPlayersText();

    void updatePlayers(std::string name, std::string age);

private slots :

    void on_buttonAdd_clicked();

    void on_button_begin_clicked();

private:

    std::vector<metier::Player> _players;

    Ui::firstWindow *ui;

    gameWindow* gameWind;
    
    bool isNumber(const std::string& str);

};

#endif // FIRSTWINDOW_H
```

fisrtWindow.cpp

```
#include "firstwindow.h"
#include "ui_firstwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>



firstWindow::firstWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::firstWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->button_add, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_buttonAdd_clicked()));
}

firstWindow::~firstWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

std::vector<metier::Player> firstWindow::getPlayers() {
    return _players;
}
bool firstWindow::isNumber(const std::string& str) {
    for (char const &c : str) {
        if (std::isdigit(c) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

std::string firstWindow::getLineEditNameText() {
     return ui->lineEdit_nom->text().toStdString();
}

std::string firstWindow::getLineEditAgeText() {
     return ui->lineEdit_age->text().toStdString();
}

void firstWindow::setPlayersText(){
    ui->text_players->append(QString::fromStdString( getLineEditNameText() + " " + getLineEditAgeText() + "ans" + "\n"));
}

void firstWindow::on_buttonAdd_clicked() {    
    if(_players.size()==6) {
        ui->label_avert_empty->setText("Vous etes déjà 6 joueurs.");
    } else if(getLineEditAgeText().empty() || getLineEditNameText().empty() || !isNumber(getLineEditAgeText()) || (stoi(getLineEditAgeText())<8)) {
            ui->label_avert_empty->setText("Vous devez remplir les 2 cases correctement.");
    } else {
        firstWindow::setPlayersText();
        metier::Player player = metier::Player(getLineEditNameText(),(_players.size()+1), stoi(getLineEditAgeText())); //stoi() transforme string to int
        _players.push_back(player);
        ui->label_avert_empty->setText("Joueur ajouté, bienvenue " + ui->lineEdit_nom->text() + " !" +"\n");
        ui->lineEdit_age->setText("");
        ui->lineEdit_nom->setText("");

    }
    qDebug() << _players.size();

}

void firstWindow::on_button_begin_clicked() {
    if(_players.size()<3) {
        ui->label_avert_less3->setText("Il faut au moins 3 joueurs.");
    } else {

        gameWind = new gameWindow(_players);
        gameWind->show();
        close();
    }

}
```

and my gameWindow.h (second window) :

```
#ifndef GAMEWINDOW_H
#define GAMEWINDOW_H

#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDialog>
#include "firstwindow.h"
#include "game.h"
#include <QLayout>

namespace Ui {
class gameWindow;
}

class gameWindow : public QDialog
{
    std::vector<metier::Player> _players;
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit gameWindow(std::vector<metier::Player> players, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    explicit gameWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~gameWindow();

    void setPlayerToPlay(int nbPlayer);

    void setPlayerHand(int player);

    // todo on an update Board
    void setPlayersBoard();

    void hideHand();
    void showHand();
    void showAnnouncedCard(metier::Card);

    void showTrueCard();
    void hideTrueCard();

    void showAnswerQuestion();
    void hideAnswerQuestion();

    void hideQuestionCard();
    void showQuestioncard();

    void showAnsweringCard();
    void hideAnsweringCard();



private:
    Ui::gameWindow *ui;

    QPushButton *button_Vrai;
    QPushButton *button_False;
    QPushButton *button_Rethrow;

};



#endif // GAMEWINDOW_H
```

If someone could help me that would be grateful. It's maybe just a small thing but i'm lost..

PS : I know my class names have to begin with an uppercase but i forgot :)

Comment: How do you build the project?

Comment: are you aware of the cyclic referencing in the code? your ***GameWindow*** includes the  ***firstWin*** and in the ***fisrtWin*** you include the ***gameWin*** as well.... that looks like a fishy design....

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you include gamewindow.h in firstwindow.h. Better to just forward declare class gameWindow in  firstwindow.h and break the include cycle.

The cycle is that gamewindow.cpp includes gamewindow.h, which includes firstwindow.h, which includes gamewindow.h...abd the ifdef guards prevent it from reading the file again so it has not seen the definition of gameWindow when it is used in firstwindow.h

Comment: Thank you a lot! I can finally move on :)